# how to resolve "No exception type(s) specifiedPylint(W0702:bare-except)" problem?

Tags: python, error-handling, pylint

I am using `dnspython` module reverse DNS resolution in a python script. If the nameserver could not find any `PTR` record for the query, it raises an exception like this:

`raise NXDOMAIN(qnames=self.qnames_to_try, dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: The DNS query name does not exist: 1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.`

I have used exception handling to workaround the problem without specifying the exception type because `NXDOMAIN` exception type is not defined as a standard exception type, but pylint detects the problem in my code.

```
from dns import resolver

try:
    query = res.resolve(q_addr, q_type)
except:
    result.append("DNS Not Found")
else:
    result.append(query)
```

`No exception type(s) specified Pylint(W0702:bare-except)`

I could not find any solution except configuring pylint so that it does not show (W0702:bare-except).

Is there any way to define new exception types in Python to work around such problems?

Comment: Why not import that error from Dnspython? https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/exceptions.html#dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN

Comment: Thanks. It is resolved.
I had no idea that I could import exceptions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) comment, I imported the exception from `dnspython`, so the problem was resolved.

```
from dns import resolver

try:
    query = res.resolve(q_addr, q_type)
except resolver.NXDOMAIN:
    result.append("DNS Not Found")
else:
    result.append(query)
```